Problem with Reading Text Using Turkish TTS Engines in WPF Project - How Can I Resolve It?
I want to establish a text-to-speech (TTS) structure in my WPF project. I'm doing this so that visually impaired users can hear information in certain parts of the application. I've used the System.Speech library. However, even though there are Turkish TTS engines in the system, I couldn't perform text-to-speech with Turkish TTS engines. When I tried to list Turkish TTS engines, it returned an empty object. As a result, I can make the system read using the English TTS engine, but that's not what I want.
What approach should I take to make the system read text with Turkish TTS engines in the project? I'd appreciate it if you could guide me on this.
Note: Turkish Vocalizer TTS, Jaws screen reader, and NVDA screen reader are available on the system.
